# How can I perform mutation tests on an F# codebase?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nunit, mstest, mutation-testing

What options are available for me to execute mutation tests on an F# codebase?

For example, are there any frameworks available?

Comment: Google suggests that such a framework doesn't exist - http://blog.bjartwolf.com/?p=4722.  Note that framework requests are off topic for SO

Comment: Thx John. Do you know of an appropriate platform for me to post this question then?

Comment: Not really - maybe the F# mailing list?

Comment: The idiomatic approach to this problem would currently be to write such a tool and share it as OSS :) That's how most of the F# tool chain has evolved the last couple of years.

Comment: Seriously, though, is there even a good answer to that question for *C#?* (Completely sincere question, in case you were wondering.)

Comment: I saw NinjaTurtles and VisualMutator. I'm just not sure if they can work with F#.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what sort of mutations you want.

Traditional mutation testing is performed by mutating at a byte-code/IL level, which means it doesn't matter what language you used to write it.

Unfortunately, there still isn't anything even nearly as mature as [PIT Java Mutation Testing](http://pitest.org/). The closest you will get is [Ninja Turtles](https://ninjaturtles.codeplex.com/), but I've had limited success with that.